# What does "./" mean in .gitignore, and why it prevents the directory from being matched?

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

The following `.gitignore` doesn't prevent `node_modules` from being tracked:

```
./cdk/node_modules/
```

While any of these do:

```
cdk/node_modules/
```

```
/cdk/node_modules/
```

I didn't find any mentioning of `./` in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Is there any meaning attached to `./` in `.gitignore`, or is it just a "dot" folder? Is it possible to have such folder at all? If not, does this mean `./` in the beginning of the `.gitignore` line is always a mistake?

Comment: Git compares the patterns to the pathname it used. It doesn't use `./` in its paths so a `./` pattern will never match anything.

Comment: @jthill If you can find a reference for that (e.g. the source code, or a quote in the manual) you could put it as an Answer. It doesn't "ask for more information or suggest improvements", though, so doesn't really belong as a Comment.

Comment: @IMSoP I've tended to use comments on lazy questions that I hope will be deleted but aren't quite worth a downvote.

Comment: @jthill All that does is reward the lazy question, because the user gets their answer and leaves happy, rather than learning how to contribute value to the site. If you think a question shouldn't be here, vote to close, downvote, or both.

Comment: What is the posix tag doing here? git isn't a POSIX-specified tool, and it behaves the way no matter which shell is used to invoke it (including whether or not that shell is POSIX-compliant).

Comment: @IMSoP SO used to have usable euphemisms among the reasons  for such closure votes, but has removed them. I'd hazard you agree a blunt ~lazy question~ closure reason would not produce results anyone wants. I've been going on the notion that steering the kids towards using whatever brains they've got before bothering the entire SO audience often requires some delicacy.

Comment: @jthill You can always leave a custom close reason (which appears as a comment, but a comment about the question, not a pseudo-answer). Or you could leave a very short answer if you think that's all the question warrants. Adding a pseudo-answer as a comment doesn't save anybody time - the question remains open, even if the asker says "thank you" and then never comes back.

Comment: @jthill Meanwhile, I'm not actually convinced this question _is_ lazy - the documentation _doesn't_ say that a `./` path won't work, and in a lot of similar contexts it would. It would be perfectly reasonable for git to normalise the paths on both sides before comparing them.

Comment: @IMSoP That easy conflation of path and pattern was why I didn't downvote and pointed out the distinction in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

When the doc says "Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern. When deciding whether to ignore a path,", it doesn't check all possible paths that could be used to reach the same file, just the one it used, the simplest one.

To get the anchoring effect, use a plain `/` in the pattern, see [the "PATTERN FORMAT" section](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format), "If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level"

Comment: I don't get it. How is that phrase from the doc proves that you're right? Please keep in mind, that I know the behavior, I'm showing it in the question. I'm asking what the behavior SHOULD BE. I thought it was clear, since this site for programmers, and not program users, who share their knowledge of how tools work.

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't find any mentioning of ./ in the doc.

This is true, it is not mentioned in the docs because it is not valid in `.gitignore`.

> ... does this mean `./` in the beginning of the `.gitignore` line is always a mistake?

Yes.